# vue-cli with webpack crashes when loading css file

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, vue.js

I'm having trouble getting a simple css file to be imported. Here are my steps to reproduce:

From command line:

```
 vue init webpack my-project
 cd my-project/
 npm install
 npm install css-loader style-loader --save-dev
```

Then in webpack.base.conf.js:

```
 {
   test: /\.css$/,
   use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
 },
```

Then I created a file src/assets/styles.css:

```
 body {
   background-color: aqua;
 }
```

Then just below the import statement in App.vue:

```
 import css from './assets/styles.css'
```

Then I start the server with:

```
 npm run dev
```

And the output is:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                   11:12:51 AM

 error  in ./src/assets/styles.css

Module build failed: Unknown word (5:1)

  3 | // load the styles
  4 | var content = require("!!../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js?{\"minimize\":false,\"sourceMap\":false}!./styles.css");
> 5 | if(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];
    | ^
  6 | if(content.locals) module.exports = content.locals;
  7 | // add the styles to the DOM
  8 | var update = require("!../../node_modules/vue-style-loader/lib/addStylesClient.js")("dfb563ca", content, false);


 @ ./src/assets/styles.css 4:14-172 13:2-17:4 14:20-178
 @ ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js

> Listening at http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: Give https://github.com/vuejs/vue-style-loader a try perhaps

Comment: @DavidL I don't think he need `vue-style-loader` specially. It is https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader enough for basic style importing inside `.vue` components.
Btw, it is strange... `vue-cli` should bundle `css` in `vue` components out of the box

Comment: I agree. I feel like this is such a common use case that I must be missing the option that automatically does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was an insignificant syntax error in my css file - the css file worked fine when the file was loaded directly using a `<link>` so I didn't notice it. The error message I posted above was really misleading, though.